# Assigning multiple aliases/nicknames to an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a music related app where artists have multiple *aliases* or *nicknames*. For example on one album the artist, *Snoop Dogg* could be credited as *Snoop Lion* on another. I was wondering what would be the best approach, Active Model wise to creating a setup where a model has one or more aliases? The first thought that comes to mind is setting up a one-to-many relationship:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :aliases
end

class Alias < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

With this being said I'm perfectly okay with being wrong about this setup. Just not sure creating a separate table for this would be most conducive. In addition to this I still needed the *alias* to be synonymous to the artist vs. the alias being exactly what it is, an `Alias` object. Any ideas on accomplishing this?

Comment: Don't worry about your associations, you can change them in future very simple by rails migrations. I would chose you way (with has_many association) if I made this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the aliases table may be the best approach in your situation, unless you want to serialize an alias column on your database.
However, going the serialize approach would make it a bit difficult, or rather inefficient to index/search for aliases on your db.
However going the aliases table approach, you could easily do

`Artist.first.aliases`

or when searching for an artist with a particular alias, you could do:

`Alias.where(name: "Snoop Lion").artist`

Also, I could imagine your songs model being:

```
class Song < AR::Base
  belongs_to :alias
  delegate :artist, to: :alias

end
```

I don't know your implementation approach, but I think this may be a good approach.